# Is it possible to "partially apply" variadic functions in go?

Tags: go, variadic-functions

Given a function declared as

```
func foo(bars ...string) {
    // ...
}
```

I'd like to call this like so:

```
bar1 := "whiskey bar"
rest := []string{"vodka bar", "wine bar"}
foo(bar1, rest...)
```

but this doesn't compile; the last line errors with this message:

```
have (string, []string...)
want (...[]string)
```

Is there a way I can declare a variadic function so that it can be called with both zero or more parameters that are values, and zero or one array of values (at the end)?

Comment: Unfortunately there isn't a way that would satisfy both of your conditions, the best you can do, i think, is something like this: `foo(append([]string{bar1}, rest...)...)`.

Comment: Also have a look at this [so answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28626170/965900).

Comment: Also related: [Is it possible to trigger compile time error with custom library in golang?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37270743/is-it-possible-to-trigger-compile-time-error-with-custom-library-in-golang/37271129#37271129)

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to change the signature to `func foo(some string, bars ...string)` as explained in the [docs](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Passing_arguments_to_..._parameters). More in the playground: https://play.golang.org/p/xlsCKzhj5y