# Call a variadic function in Go

Tags: go, slice, variadic

I have code where I am calling `filepath.Join` as described in the following program.
However, I see an error

Program:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "path/filepath"
)

func main() {
    myVal := joinPath("dir1", "dir2")
    fmt.Println(myVal)
}

func joinPath(dirs ...string) string {
    return filepath.Join("mydir", dirs...)
}
```

Error:
`./prog.go:16:32: too many arguments in call to filepath.Join have (string, []string) want (...string)`

While I know this is a legitimate error, how do I join the path with a default parent directory using Join

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't mix a slice and explicit elements for a variadic parameter, for details, see [mixing "exploded" slices and regular parameters in variadic functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28625546/mixing-exploded-slices-and-regular-parameters-in-variadic-functions/28626170#28626170)

However, in your special case you may call `filepath.Join()` twice, and get the same result:

```
func joinPath(dirs ...string) string {
    return filepath.Join("mydir", filepath.Join(dirs...))
}
```

You may also prepare a slice with all elements, and pass that like this:

```
func joinPath(dirs ...string) string {
    return filepath.Join(append([]string{"mydir"}, dirs...)...)
}
```

Both will return and output (try them on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/NbLH7J8O9GE)):

```
mydir/dir1/dir2
```